# Code Signature Invalid with SIP enabled in macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, macos-bigsur, code-signing

I'm trying to install some app on macOS Big Sur 11.3, which requires disabling SIP to authorize the application from settings > security & privacy. Problem is: the app is installed and works perfectly fine when SIP is disabled. Whenever I enable SIP after the installation and authorization step **OR** I try to install the app with SIP enabled, I get the crash report below. Is there a workaround for the app to install and work as expected with SIP enabled? I found an earlier unanswered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63916547/mac-why-do-code-sign-invalidate-when-sip-is-enabled) addressing the same issue.

```
System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x1

kernel messages:

VM Regions Near 0 (cr2):
--> 
    __TEXT                      102098000-1022f8000    [ 2432K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  

Thread 0 Crashed:
0                                   0x000000010876e000 _dyld_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x00007ffeedb67bd0
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x000000010876e000  rfl: 0x0000000000000200  cr2: 0x0000000000000000
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     0

Thread 0 instruction stream not available.

Thread 0 last branch register state not available.


Binary Images:
       0x102098000 -        0x1022f7fff +??? (0) <AC4BC812-F8E7-3E28-B309-783E619CBEB6> (null)
       0x10876d000 -        0x108808fff + (851.27) <7EAA668B-F906-3BAA-A980-139BBE6E8766> 

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=3520K resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=3520K(100%)
Writable regions: Total=8432K written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=8432K(100%)
 
                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        1 
Stack                             8192K        1 
VM_ALLOCATE                          8K        2 
__DATA                             896K        4 
__DATA_CONST                        32K        1 
__LINKEDIT                         496K        4 
__TEXT                            3056K        2 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                             68.4M       15 

Model: MacBookPro12,1, BootROM 427.0.0.0.0, 2 processors, Dual-Core Intel Core i5, 2.7 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.28f7
Graphics: kHW_IntelIris6100Item, Intel Iris Graphics 6100, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x4544464132333241324D412D4A442D460000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x4544464132333241324D412D4A442D460000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x133), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.111.1 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1680.7)
Bluetooth: Version 8.0.4d18, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0128G, 121.33 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

Comment: Code Signature Invalid - ask the developer.